# Requesting Advice: Categorize Account Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have recently inherited a very messy Dynamics CRM system from my predecessor. I want to clean up the way our company navigates around Accounts. At the moment, there are 3 views and one form with about 2000 (exaggeration) lines of javascript code!

We categorize accounts into three types; TypeA, TypeB, TypeC. This is controlled by an Option Drop Down. Once selected, the screen hides/shows depending on it. This has meant we have a very wide AccountExtensionBase table. I am accepting I will have to live with this as I am have been led to believe that building a 1..1 extension is not as easy as it seems?

What I would like to do is change the 'Workplace -> Customer' menu on the right hand side of CRM. I'd like to add three clickable options so it would read

Customers

- Accounts
- TypeA
- TypeB
- TypeC
- Contacts

Upon clicking, for example, 'TypeA' it would take the user to the 'TypeA' accounts which are filtered by a pre-defined view. Then, any request for the Account Form from this view would redirect the user to a specific 'TypeA' form, which I have yet to create.

I have read this article here [Crm 2011 - How to set a default form depending on attribute value (without using Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340764/crm-2011-how-to-set-a-default-form-depending-on-attribute-value-without-using) which is a good example of how to re-direct the forms. However, I am unsure how to handle this from a 'New' request, as the drop down is not yet populated.

Is there a way of building this concept cleanly in CRM? I am finding it hard to get any decent Google results as I am unsure of what terminology I should be using.

Any help or links to suitable guides would be hugely appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt this is doable, and I'm sure that the "context-dependant" behavior involved in the "New" form depending on the view isn't. They need a custom webapplication for customizations this deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the droids you are looking for:
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/03/08/displaying-filtered-view-in-site-map-crm-2011/
Granted it is for CRM 4, however it may work in 2011.

You might also look at:
http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/06/new-tool-sitemap-editor-for-microsoft.html

Comment: Thank for your reply Robert - your links have given me a more than adequate starting point.